# Preventing Date transformation in the browser?

Tags: javascript, datetime, amcharts4

I'm getting a date range from the input fields (dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss) which I would like to keep it exactly as received, without letting the browser convert it to local timezone. How can I do this?

I've tried using a function to convert the date in a different readable format but still, the browser is changing the date.

```
<input type='datetime-local' class="form-control" step="1" id="startRange" />
<input type='datetime-local' class="form-control" step="1" id="endRange" />

let datePickStart = new Date(document.getElementById("startRange").value);
let datePickEnd = new Date(document.getElementById("endRange").value);
console.log(datePickStart);
console.log(datePickEnd);


let startRangeDate = dateConvert(datePickStart);
let endRangeDate = dateConvert(datePickEnd);
console.log(startRangeDate);
console.log(endRangeDate);

function appendLeadingZeroes(n) {
    if (n <= 9) {
        return "0" + n;
    }
    return n
}

function dateConvert(dateToConvert) {

    let dateString = dateToConvert.getFullYear() + "-" + appendLeadingZeroes(dateToConvert.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + appendLeadingZeroes(dateToConvert.getDate());
    let timeString = appendLeadingZeroes(dateToConvert.getHours()) + ":" + appendLeadingZeroes(dateToConvert.getMinutes()) + ":" + appendLeadingZeroes(dateToConvert.getSeconds());
    // Prevent conversion of date in the browser?
    let dateFiltered = dateString + "T" + timeString;
    return dateFiltered;
}
```

I'm expecting the date received from input to remain exactly the same, without being changed by the browser to local timezone. Here's a [JSFiddle I did:](https://jsfiddle.net/q32kydfx/9/)

Comment: you need to use the UTC date functions in javascript instead. every date function (like `date.getFullYear` has a UTC counterpart (like `date.getUTCFullYear`). check out the sidebar on the [mdn date page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for the rest of the utc functions.

Comment: unless you print it as a string as it is, it will not be possible to force a dateformat because it is controlled by the client pc locale

Comment: @Mox I see. So I must convert to string. Thanks!

Comment: @JustMe, i think in javascript, there is a way to print the time in a certain time format

Comment: [`toLocalseDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) is teh native way to format a string. you may also benefit from a library like my own [protodate](https://pamblam.github.io/protodate/) which makes both formatting and timezone conversion easy.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Thank you very much for the library link!

Answer (score 1):

These kind of tasks always appear in frontend development. It is a good idea to use a popular and well maintained library for working with date and time, for all kinds of reasons, such as:

- Support for internationalization
- Support for various datetime formats
- Support for calculations with datetimes (for instance, deciding if a datetime is in the future)

These libraries are also well tested and tried by a large community. When you develop your own code, many bugs can appear. We use [Moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).

Comment: Thanks! I think I will go the library way, to avoid any headaches